# Protect logfiles for php applications

Tags: php, apache, file-extension, logfiles

I log sensitive information in a a log file lets call it "mylogfile.log". This file should in no circumstances be access from the outside/web.

I already protect it  by using a .htaccess file but what i would like some extra safeguard like using a fileextension that is protected by the system. Is there any such?

The reason for the extra security is that this webapp is distrubuted to clients that could change or remove the .htaccess file. Also .htaccess override needs to be enabled in Apache.

Comment: put the files outside the `/home/server/public_html` like `/home/server/logs`

Comment: its a good suggestion, but i'm not sure that i can know the full path to anything else then the website, as this will be installed on many different servers.

Comment: @ttony now I read your comment, sorry for partly stealing your answer..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put it outside of the document root.

If **/var/www/your-site.com/public** matches the URI *your-site.com* (public/index.html --> your-site.com/index.html etc), then log files will not be readable if you place them in **/var/www/your-site.com/logs**

When distributing an app like this, I would always make sure that you, given your limited and controlled space, do not use your "base folder" as the document root of the webserver, just to get some privacy around it.

Comment: +1 don't worry, I had not the time to answer the question so I just published a comment